# Is it possible to scroll through a long body of data using two columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was hoping to see if I could get some help making this work. I'm working on a Chrome extension that modifies the layout of a site with `CSS/js` tweaks.

Is it possible to make the long, narrow text on this page scroll like the following diagram displays?

Site: https://play.date/pulp/docs/pulpscript/

Diagram:
[image]

Latest attempt at solution:

```
var curColumn = 0;

main.onscroll = function(){myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    if (curColumn==0 && document.documentElement.scrollTop == 0) {
        // do nothing
    }
    else if (curColumn==2 && document.documentElement.scrollBottom == 0) {
        // do nothing
    }
    else {
        // move forward or backward? 
        // where to increment/decrement curColumn?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you would need a counter in JS to keep track of the current column, then in the container element you could add an onscroll method, that when it reaches the bottom or top it will move to the other end of the document based on what the current column is. Then increment or decrement the column number.

If `column == 0` and we reach the top of the page, do nothing, likewise for the bottom of the page and the last column. Else, move forward or backward.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

Could you explain it to me with a bit more detail? In the original question, I've added the code structure based on your comment. I'm just having a bit of trouble figuring out the functionality inside each condition you've mentioned.

Comment: Absolutely, so if we have conditions where we do nothing, we can safely omit them, as they're dead code anyway. You should ideally have two conditions 

`document.documentElement.scrollBottom == 0 && curColumn != 2 // we're scrolling down but not at the bottom of the last column yet` 
and 
`document.documentElement.scrollTop == 0 && curColumn != 0 // we're scrolling up but not at the top of the first column yet`. 

Then in each condition you can move the page to the opposite end and increment/decrement the column as appropriate.